# Regular expression for 5 numbers and 1 Alphabet

Tags: regex

Need help to define a regex pattern for 5 numbers and 1 Alphabet. I have defined something like this:

```
"(?<Code>\d{5}){1}(?<Id>[a-zA-Z]{1}){1}$"
```

The above pattern also matches "1234567A". How to restrict the numeric to 5 digits in the above pattern?

Comment: Did you forgot `^` to define the beginning of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use anchors at the begining and the end:

```
^\d{5}[a-zA-Z]$
```

or if the string is inside another string:

```
\b\d{5}[a-zA-Z]\b
```